# iOS use cached image with SDWebImage properly

Tags: objective-c, ios6, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage to get pictures.

let's say I have two view controllers A and B. B is the next view of A. they need to show the same image:

```
[iconIamgeView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/icon.jpg"];
```

I thought SDWebImage would cache `http://www.example.com/icon.jpg` after this code in A, so B was going to use the cache. Thus there should not be a detectable latency when I used this code to show the same image in B. However, it seems that I was wrong. there was an obvious latency when I wanted to show this image in B.

How can I use the cache properly? thanks!

Comment: do u have #import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h> added? and the settings properly set? it should have worked

Comment: yes, I have imported the header. I can use SDWebImage successfully without the cache part. what do you mean "the settings properly set"? thanks!

Comment: i meant the installation steps for SDWebImage

Comment: yeah, as I can use it, I think I've installed it successfully. So, in normal case, SDWebImage should cache the image when using `setImageWithURL`, right?

Comment: yeah, pretty straight forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry that the problem I mentioned in the question was not the real problem.

```
[iconIamgeView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/icon.jpg"];
```

**this code does the cache work well.**

the real problem is my code of setting image was not on the main thread, so I could not show the image immediately. I used `dispatch_async` to solve the problem:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [iconIamgeView setImageWithURL:[NSURLURLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/icon.jpg"];
});
```

hope this answer may help someone who faces the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[linkImageArray objectAtIndex:index]];
UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed : [linkImageArray objectAtIndex: index]];

[imageView setImageWithURL:imageURL
          placeholderImage:placeholderImage
                   options:SDWebImageRefreshCached
                 completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
                   {
                       NSLog(@"image loaded");
                   }];
```

Comment: Please fix the post. Currently, it is a dumped mess.